# Why does TeX hyphenate analysis as anal-ysis?

Tags: babel, hyphenation

I am having the following issue when the word analysis is hyphenated in TeX.

[image]

This is using `\usepackage[british]{babel}` in the header.
I have figured out how to work around the issue, by manually setting the hyphenation:

```
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{a-na-ly-sis}
```

Still, I am curious why this is not handled automatically. Beyond the obvious undesirable connotation of this hyphenation, it seems to me that the "ly" in analysis should definitely belong together.

Comment: When did you last update your TeX distribution? With MacTeX2019 and `\usepackage[british]{babel}`, I get `ana-lysis` and `ana-lytic`.

Comment: @Mico I'm on texlive 2019

Comment: And when did you last update TeXLive2019? With the most recent updates to TeXLive2019, as well as with the prerelease version of TeXLive2020, I am unable to generate the outcome you have identified.

Comment: I get `ana-lysis` as the only suggested break point. (Fully updated MikTeX with `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5`, `L3 programming layer <2020-04-06>`)

Comment: Run the minimal example posted by Mico and upload the  complete `.log` file to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/

Comment: Here is one: With `american` I get `anal-y-sis`. The word is among the known "hyphenation exceptions" for American English, see https://ctan.org/pkg/hyphenex (and several TUGBoat articles). So maybe your document doesn't have the British pattern available. It appears to be quite tricky to find out which patterns are loaded into the format, so I doubt I'll be able to help.

Comment: To retrieve the available languages, add the option `showlanguages` to `babel` (ie, `\usepackage[british, showlanguages]{babel}`. They are listed in the .log file.

Answer (score 3):

Your installation of TeX Live is missing the support for UK English.

How to add it on Gentoo Linux is difficult to say; check https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/dev-texlive/texlive-langenglish

I can reproduce the issue if I remove the support for UK English:

```latex
\makeatletter
\let\l@UKenglish\@undefined
\let\l@ukenglish\@undefined
\let\l@british\@undefined
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\showhyphens{analysis}
```

This produces

```latex
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--10
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 anal-y-sis
```

because, when a language which is not provided with hyphenation patterns is requested, `babel` will use language 0 (US English).

After removing the initial lines I get

```latex
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 12--12
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ana-lysis
```

because my installation *does* have support for UK English.

Comment: I can confirm that sadly I get your first output from both versions, this being my log: https://chymera.eu/debug/tex/hyphenation/with_babel.log

Comment: @TheChymera Install a *full* TeX Live.

Answer (score 0):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I am unable to replicate the issue you have encountered with either TeXLive2019 (with all updates applied, `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5`, `babel 2020/02/28 3.41`, and `british 2017/06/06 v3.3r`) or with TeXLive2020 (pre-release version, same LaTeX2e and babel versions as above).

[image]

When did you last update your TeX distribution, and which versions of `babel` and the `british` language support block does your document employ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat} % optional
\setlength\textwidth{1sp}
\begin{document} 
\hspace{0pt}analysis analytic Arseneau % as in 'Donald Arseneau'
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the latest texlive version available on Gentoo Linux, installed just a few days ago: `Installed versions:  2019-r1(01:25:00 AM 04/02/2020)`. Could it be some subpackage, or is this really baked into texlive?

Comment: @TheChymera - I'm afraid I have no idea how up-to-date the Gentoo Linux distribution may be. (I use MacOS 10.15.4 "Catalina" and both MacTeX2019 and MacTeX2020.) What information can you glean from the log file regarding the version of LaTeX2e, babel, and the 'british' language module that get employed when you compile the document that features the unfortunate hyphenation instance?

Comment: @Mico Suggestion: add `showlanguages` to the `babel` options.

Comment: @Mico with your code I get this log: http://chymera.eu/debug/tex/hyphenation/full_with_babel.log and this output document: http://chymera.eu/debug/tex/hyphenation/fulltest.pdf

Comment: @TheChymera - Thanks. According to the log file, your TeX system has an out-dated version of the LaTeX2e format (`<2018-12-01>`; current is `<2020-02-02> patch level 5`) and copies of unknown vintage of the `babel` package and of the `british`  module. Any chance you could run `sudo tlmgr update --self --all` from a command prompt and recompile the document?